# Run prestashop application and angular application from same domain

Tags: php, angular, apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I have two applications: a Prestashop php app and an Angular 10 app.
What I want to achieve is this:
when I navigate to "http://example.com/" the angular app should respond, when I navigate to "http://example.com/shop/" I should be on the prestashop store.
For now what I achieved is this:
when I navigate to "http://example.com/app/", the angular app responds and when I navigate to "http://example.com/" the prestashop app responds.

The Apache virtual host configuration is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prestashop/"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prestashop/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All        
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyStatus On
    ProxyPass           /app/    http://localhost:4200/
    ProxyPassReverse    /app/    http://localhost:4200/
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I do?

Comment: This might be a good use for an [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html) in Apache. Then you configure different  document root and settings for `/shop` in the same virtual host.

Comment: What prevents you from running the angular app on port 80 and running Prestashop on another port and do the same thing using the proxy?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't understand what are you saying. Could you make an example?

Comment: @ParaD same question as above :)